# Using SocketIo Manager with a default URL

Tags: socket.io

My goal is to add a token in the socketio reconnection from the client (works fine on the first connection, but the query is null on the reconnection, if the server restarted while the client stayed on).
The documentation indicates I need to use the Manager to customize the reconnection behavior (and add a query parameter).
However, I'm getting trouble finding how to use this Manager: I can't find a way to connect to the server.

What I was using without Manager (works fine):

```
this.socket = io({
  query: {
    token: 'abc',
  }
});
```

Version with the Manager:

```
const manager = new Manager(window.location, { 
  hostname: "localhost",
  path: "/socket.io",
  port: "8080",
  query: {
    auth: "123"
  }
});
```

So I tried many approaches (nothing, '', 'http://localhost:8080', 'http://localhost:8080/socket.io', adding those lines to the options:

```
 hostname: "localhost",
  path: "/socket.io",
  port: "8080" in the options,
```

But I couldn't connect.

The documentation indicates the default URL is:
url (String) (defaults to window.location)

For some reasons, using window.location as URL refreshes the page infinitely, no matter if I enter it as URL in the io() creator or in the new Manager.

I am using socket.io-client 3.0.3.
Could someone explain me what I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Updating to 3.0.4 solved the initial problem, which was to be able to send the token in the initial query.
I also found this code in the doc, which solves the problem:

```
this.socket.on('reconnect_attempt', () => {
  socket.io.opts.query = {
    token: 'fgh'
  }
});
```

However, it doesn't solve the problem of the Manager that just doesn't work. I feel like it should be removed from the doc. I illustrated the problem in this repo:
https://github.com/Yvanovitch/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/public/main.js